# Determine host name via IP address

Tags: windows, powershell

I need the hostname from my default gateway. It is a Vyos gateway. I can resolve the IP-address by the hostname but not vice verca.

I'm able to get the IP-address from the gateway:

```
Get-NetRoute -DestinationPrefix "0.0.0.0/0" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "NextHop"
172.20.1.29
```

But when I try Resolve-DnsName with that IP, I recieve an error

```
Resolve-DnsName 172.20.1.29
Resolve-DnsName : 29.1.20.172.in-addr.arpa : DNS name does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName 172.20.1.29
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (29.1.20.172.in-addr.arpa:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName
```

Comment: You can try: ```nslookup -a <ip address>```

Comment: What happens if you use your gateway as dns server: `Resolve-DnsName 172.20.1.29 -Server 172.20.1.29` ?

Comment: `Resolve-DnsName : 29.1.20.172.in-addr.arpa : DNS name does not exist` - that error tells you that your DNS servers have no PTR records for turning that IP back to the hostname. "Reverse DNS" queries to get names from IPs are the same as normal DNS queries, but asking for a name in that `in-addr.arpa` namespace instead. The DNS server has to be configured to answer those kinds of queries. That is, the fix for this is not code but setting up your environment to support the thing you want to do, or accepting some workaround for it.

Comment: @ag00se that gives me the name of the domain controller.